# Scroller doesn't reach the end of Scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar, scrollview

The scroller of the scrollbar is not reaching the end of the scrollbar even though there is no more content to scroll.

Here is a screenshot

[image]

I want the scroller to reach the end of the scrollbar as it reaches the end of the content in div.

Any ideas?

Edit:

```
.long-list {
    height: 300px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/nsLtg6j7/1/)

Thanks

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: @jmore009: I have added JSfiddle link in the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a stupid mistake in my CSS code.

Since I have given overflow: scroll, I think it has alloted some space for horizontal scrollbar. Once I changed it to overflow: scroll-y, its working perfectly.

Here is the updated [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nsLtg6j7/6/)

```
.long-list {
    height: 300px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```